# How to refer to a part previously mentioned in a report

Tags: reference

I am writing my thesis and when I want to refer to something I will talk about later I use: *see section/chapter...*. But can I use it for a chapter that the reader should already have read?

Because in French, it would be strange to use *voir*, and we will mostly use *cf.* (confer) in that purpose (it can be used for previous and following parts). However, in English *cf.* doesn't have the same meaning. I saw also q.v. (quod vide), but is it actually used?

Comment: I suggest you find some theses for the area you're writing in and see what they use; it should be easy to search the text. Personally "see" is fine, or "as already described in..." if you prefer.

Comment: *q.v.* is definitely used in scholarly writing. You can also use "refer to chapter N"

Comment: Thanks, both of you for your comments. I'll use your suggestions as well as q.v. Thanks!

Comment: Less formally, you can also say "see chapter X above" for previous chapters, and "see chapter Y below" for later ones.

Comment: There's always this -- *5 Latin Terms in Referencing* https://getproofed.com.au/writing-tips/5-latin-terms-referencing/

Comment: Modern English would be happier with 'As will be discussed / As we will discuss in chapter 6' etc than with archaisms.

Answer (score 1):

One quite formal way of doing this is to use the word *supra.* [Cambridge provides this definition:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/supra)

> used in a text to refer to something mentioned earlier

They also provide this example sentence:

> See McHoul note 33 (*supra*), for a discussion of these possibilities.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that later text is referred to using _ante_.